# How to feed data from Excel to Toad SQL and create as view

Tags: sql, excel, vba, automation, toad

is it possible to feed data from the excel sheet into Toad SQL(as View)

Basically copy all the data from the sheet and keep it as VIEW in Toad, which I can use for my other queries

Answer (score 0):

I’m sure there are a few ways to accomplish that. One example would be writing a script that reads the excel data into variables that could then be inserted into toad via command line or GUI. I’m not familiar with toad but I’m sure it can be done.

Comment: Tourless could provide any link which I can follow to get an understanding of the script. thanks in advance